# How to align a <ul> in right side of a side menu?

Tags: html, css

I have created a side menu in div and added another div for desc for the side menu.
But when i try to add the second div it is coming to the bottom of the first div.
How can i fix this. Please help me on this. Giving the html and css.

```css
.sidemenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: background;
    width: 15%;
    list-style-type: square;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidemenu li{
    padding: 5px;
}
.topics ul{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
        <div class="sidemenu">

            <ul>
                <li><b>Categories</b></li>
                <hr style="margin-top: -2px;">
                <li><a href="">Categoryname</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        
<div class="topics">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial">
                        <b>
                            
                                Topicname
                            
                        </b>                
                    </font>                    
                </li>
                
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the `.sidemenu ul` on the right, or the `.topics ul`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple float? Give `float: right` to the side menu UL.

```css
.sidemenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: background;
    width: 15%;
    list-style-type: square;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.sidemenu li{
    padding: 5px;
}
.sidemenu li.sep {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.sidemenu li.sep hr {margin-top: -3px;}
.topics ul{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidemenu">
  <ul>
    <li><b>Categories</b></li>
    <li class="sep"><hr /></li>
    <li><a href="">Categoryname</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="topics">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial">
        <b>

          Topicname

        </b>                
      </font>                    
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [float:right](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) to this class `.sidemenu ul{}`

Answer (score 0):

```
  .sidemenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: background;
    width: 15%;
    list-style-type: square;
    height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
.sidemenu li{
    padding: 5px;
}
.topics ul{
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    add Width Property;
}
```

and Keep the html as it is